# "Unsupported Media Type", 415 eror when post request in react-native

Tags: c#, json, react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch my asp .net core API in react-native app. When I am testing with Postman this API is working fine, but in react-native I have this error:

> ["https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13", "Unsupported Media Type", 415, "00-2608a636e0aeaf4bb2b29a2e1b54370a-2145e9063626d940-00"]

This is my API. I have tried public `JsonResult` but nothing changes.

```
 [HttpPost("register")]
        public IActionResult Register([FromBody] TbPersonel model)
        {
            try
            {
                // SOME CASES

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    model.login = true;                   
                    return new JsonResult(model.login);
                }
                else
                {
                    model.login = false;                   
                    return new JsonResult(model.login);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logla.Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName, e);
                return new JsonResult(e);
            }
        }
```

React-Native

```
 fetch('http:/.../api/login/register/',{
            method:'post',
            header:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                // 'Content-type': 'application/json'
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({               
                'kullaniciAdi': userName,
                'sifre': userPassword
            })          
        })    
        .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson)=>{
       console.log(Object.values(responseJson));
```

[image: Postman Post request]

[image: Postman headers]

Comment: give only `'Content-Type': 'application/json;`. and try `{               
                "kullaniciAdi": userName,
                "sifre": userPassword
            }`

Comment: Same result, not working.

Comment: You can check the network tab in browser console

Comment: @İbrahimEthemBildirici could you provide the body of TbPersonel

Comment: public partial class TbPersonel
    {
       
        public string KullaniciAdi { get; set; }
        public string Sifre { get; set; }
        public string Aciklama { get; set; }
        public bool? Aktif { get; set; }
        public bool? Silindi { get; set; }
        public bool login { get; set; }..... more line
    }

Comment: Where can i find this settings? @AbdelkrimBournane

Comment: @İbrahimEthemBildirici in your Startup.cs

Comment: There are 2 image end of the question. Include postman request body and header @ErmiyaEskandary https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Atq.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hPkH.png

Comment: @İbrahimEthemBildirici Can you try without the `'Accept': 'application/json'` header in the fetch or change it to `'Accept': '*/*'`? My lead is that "true" returned in the Postman is not a valid Json object

Comment: i have tried before and not working 'Accept': '*/*'. Same result @AbdelkrimBournane

Comment: Am i doing it in browser? I can't understand fully.  @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: eror is caused by  this line  `console.log(Object.values(responseJson));` and output is in console :  ["https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13", "Unsupported Media Type", 415, "00-21da0995e6e066488bcfebb8f7d70a20-d5e00676b1cee342-00"]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055059/take-a-picture-and-after-successfully-receiving-a-response-i-we-need-to-call-the someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the parameters of fetch. fetch doesn't have any parameter named `header` but it's `headers` with an s. So, your code wasn't asking for the correct Content-type and Accept Headers. To fix this just add an s to the header key :

```
fetch('http:/.../api/login/register/',{
        method:'post',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            // 'Content-type': 'application/json'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({               
            'kullaniciAdi': userName,
            'sifre': userPassword
        })          
    })    
    .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson)=>{
   console.log(Object.values(responseJson));
```

Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't highlight this error.

Comment: Welcome, we struggled with that Haha!