# Take a picture and after successfully receiving a response I we need to call the endpoint - REACT NATIVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a screen where on click on image I need to open camera and take photo, I successfully open camera, take a picture but when I need to call the endpoints it show me error 415, unsupported media.

```
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} onPress={() => onPressLaunchCamera(onSuccessPhotoUpload)}>
```

Here is my function

```
const onSuccessPhotoUpload = async (response: ImagePickerResponse): Promise<void> => {
    let fileUri = '';
    if (response?.assets) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const requestBody = {
            formFile: response.assets[0],
        };
        console.log(response);
        fileUri = response?.assets[0].uri || '';

        try {
            Keyboard.dismiss();
            if (challenge) {
                formData.append('uploadPicture', {
                    uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? fileUri : fileUri.replace('file://', ''),
                    type: 'multipart/form-data',
                });
                dispatch(uploadInvoice(challenge.id, requestBody));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert('Something went wrong while getting your image from your photo library.');
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**415 Unsupported Media Type**

Fixing a 415 error can be time-consuming for the client as it indicates the issue is in what the client is sending that the web server can't process. In other words, if you come across a 415 error, it means that you have to fix the error yourself.

Here are the three most common ways for fixing a 415 Unsupported Media Type:

- Make sure that you are sending the right `Content-Type` header value.
- Confirm that the server can process the value defined in the `Content-Type` header.
- Check the Accept header to see what the server can process.

Source is [Here](https://www.exai.com/blog/415-unsupported-media-type)

Comment: Maybe I don't send image to right path?

Comment: @user16599051 may be right path or may be `Content-Type` isn't correct.